# Join mysql query with multiple counts

Tags: mysql, join, count

My tables:

tournaments

```
 _______________________________________
| id |        name          | date      |
|---------------------------|-----------|
| 12 | mytournament         | 2016-01-01|
|---------------------------|-----------|
```

players

```
 ________________________
| idt |   name      | cat |
|-------------------|-----|
|  12 | john        |  A  |
|  12 | bobby       |  A  |
|  12 | anna        |  B  |
|  12 | Fritz       |  B  |
|  12 | george      |  C  |
|-------------------|-----|
```

I would need a query that returns this:

```
id | name | date | nr of cat A | nr of cat B | nr of cat C 

12 | mytournament | 2016-01-01 | 2 | 2 | 1
```

I am havint problems with the multiple count... Can't figure out how to join the query.

```
select t.id, t.name, t.date, count(p.cat) as countA from tournaments t join players p on (t.id = p.idt)
```

but I can not figure out how to specify it should only take the count where cat = A and how to add the additional counts for B and C.

any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a classic pivot table. Therefore your statement should look something like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.date,
       COUNT(
            CASE 
                WHEN p.`cat`='A' 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
            END
       ) AS 'countA',
       COUNT(
            CASE 
                WHEN p.`cat`='B' 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
            END
       ) AS 'countB',
       COUNT(
            CASE 
                WHEN p.`cat`='C' 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
            END
       ) AS 'countC'
FROM tournaments t 
INNER JOIN players p ON t.id = p.idt
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Have a look at this [Stack overflow question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table/7675121#7675121) for more details.

Comment: `NULL` is the default `ELSE` for `CASE` statement, no need to include it.

Comment: Very true, I usually use it in answers like this for clarification.

Comment: works great, except for an error to correct. after the 3 when there should be p.`cat` and not t.`cat`. thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I've adjusted my answer accordingly.